Can ordinal spaces be Dowker spaces?
Can an ordinal space be Dowker? My guess is no; however, I don't have a proof. Here is my progress:
I know Dowker spaces are not countably paracompact.
It seems that if the ordinal $\alpha$ is a successor then $[0,\alpha)$ is compact so it is countably paracompact and not Dowker. (If this is not correct please tell me.)
If the ordianl $\alpha$ is a limit then I want to know if the product of $[0,\alpha)$ with the unit interval $[0,1]$ is normal.
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint closed subsets of $[0,\alpha)\times[0,1]$ under the product topology.
For each ordinal $\beta<\alpha$, let $A_\beta=A\cap(\{\beta\}\times[0,1])$ and $B_\beta=B\cap(\{\beta\}\times[0,1])$. $A_\beta$ and $B_\beta$ must be closed as they are the intersection of two closed sets. So maybe there is a way to choose sets $C_\beta$ and $D_\beta$ such that for all ordinals $\beta<\alpha$ the following properties are satisfied:

$A_\beta\subseteq C_\beta\subseteq\{\beta\}\times[0,1]$
$B_\beta\subseteq D_\beta\subseteq\{\beta\}\times[0,1]$

and the sets $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}C_\beta$ and $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}D_\beta$ are disjoint and open. But I don't know how to construct these $C_\beta$ and $D_\beta$.

@Ulli I couldn't find the reference you told me.

There is a more direct proof that any LOTS is countably paracompact, see Engelking exercise 5.2.22. I've worked out the proof in chat, beginning from this comment. This is by showing that an open cover of a LOTS has star-refinement iff it has a point-countable refinement.

Monotonically normal spaces are countably paracompact, hence all LOTs (= linearly ordered topological spaces) are countably paracompact. In particular, there is no ordinal space, which is Dowker. See the article of M. E. Rudin in the Handbook of set theoretic topology (1994), theorems 2.2, 2.3. But as she mentioned, proofs are not so easy.
But, indeed, there is an easy proof for ordinal spaces:
Let $\kappa$ be an ordinal with the order topology.
If $\kappa = 0$ or successor ordinal, then $\kappa$ is compact, hence paracompact.
If $\kappa$ is limit ordinal of uncountable cofinality, then
$\kappa$ is countably compact, hence countably paracompact.

So let $\kappa$ be a limit ordinal of countable cofinality,
$(\alpha_n)_{n < \omega}$ strictly increasing and cofinal in $\kappa$, w.l.o.g. $\alpha_0 = 0$.
Then for each $n$,
$(\alpha_n, \alpha_{n+1}] = [\alpha_n+1, \alpha_{n+1}]   
= (\alpha_n, \alpha_{n+1}+1)$ is clopen in $\kappa$ and
$(\alpha_n, \alpha_{n+1}]$ is compact.
Same holds for $\{0\}$.

Hence, $\kappa$ is the sum of compact, in particular countably paracompact, spaces, and therefore countably paracompact.
BTW: if you are interested in Dowker spaces, I strongly recommend to read the above mentioned article of M.E. Rudin. I guess, it's not available online, so you should check with a library. (I'm sure, every mathematical or university library has it.)
